# Memory usage in IE for gwt application

Tags: image, gwt, memory, internet-explorer-9

For the last couple of days I've been trying to find out why my gwt application is leaking on IE 9.
I want to share one of my findings with you and maybe someone can give me a clue about what is going one here...
I wrote this small test:

```
public class Memory implements EntryPoint
{
    FlowPanel mainPanel = new FlowPanel();
    FlowPanel buttonsPanel = new FlowPanel();
    FlowPanel contentPanel = new FlowPanel();

    Timer timer;

    Date startDate;

    public void onModuleLoad()
    {
        mainPanel.setWidth("100%");
        mainPanel.setHeight("100%");

        RootPanel.get().add(mainPanel);

        Button startBtn = new Button("start test");
        startBtn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
            {
                startDate = new Date();
                System.out.println("Started at " + startDate);
                timer = new Timer()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        Date now = new Date();
                        if(isWithin5Minutes(startDate, now))
                        {
                            manageContent();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Complete at " + new Date());
                            timer.cancel();
                            contentPanel.clear();
                        }
                    }
                };
                timer.scheduleRepeating(50);
            } 
        });

        buttonsPanel.add(startBtn);

        mainPanel.add(buttonsPanel);
        mainPanel.add(contentPanel);
    }

    private void manageContent()
    {
        if(contentPanel.getWidgetCount() > 0)
        {
            contentPanel.clear();
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i =0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                Image image = new Image();
                image.setUrl("/images/test.png");
                contentPanel.add(image);
            }
        }
    }


    private boolean isWithin5Minutes(Date start, Date now)
    {
        //true if 'now' is within 5 minutes of 'start' date
    }

}
```

So, I have this Timer that runs every 50 ms (during around 5 minutes) and executes the following:
- if the panel has content, clear it;
- if the panel has no content add 20 png images (30x30 with transparency) to it.

Using the Process Explorer from sysInternals I got the following results:

IE 9:
[image]

Firefox 21.0:
[image]

I ran the same program with some changes (.jpg images instead of .png, create the images only once and use them as member variables, create the images using a ClientBundle) but the result was the same. Also, I ran the application in production mode.

Is there something wrong with my code that could cause this behavior in IE?
Shouldn't the Garbage Collector (GC) free some of the used memory at least when the timer ends?
Any of you came across this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collector in IE is quite strange thing. E.g. you can force it to run by simply minimizing browser window. I guess leaks in your case are images that weren't removed properly by browser when you clear container. Try to remove them by using JS "delete" operation, like that:

```
private native void utilizeElement(Element element) /*-{
  delete element;
}-*/;
```

Then change your manageContent a little:

```
    if(contentPanel.getWidgetCount() > 0)
    {
        for (Iterator<Widget> it = contentPanel.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
            utilizeElement(it.next().getElement());
        contentPanel.clear();
    }
```

Hope this helps.